# How does JNI function (isSameObject) implement in native code?

Tags: java-native-interface

I know the code below can compare whether obj1 and obj2 share with a same reference:

```
(*env)->IsSameObject(env, obj1, obj2)
```

Actually, I try to check these two objects' ref directly like:

```
jboolean result = (obj1 == obj2);
```

But the result is different from the result of "IsSameObject".

I was wondering how does IsSameObject implement, and why the result of (obj1 == obj2) is different?

Comment: Your equality check can fail if one of the operands is a `GlobalRef` to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNI handles are not direct pointers to Java objects. Java objects can move across Heap during garbage collection. Their memory addresses may change, but JNI handles must remain valid.

JNI handles are opaque to user, that is, the implementation of handles is JVM-specific. JNI functions like `IsSameObject` provide the abstraction layer.

In HotSpot JVM handles are pointers to mutable object references.
`IsSameObject` performs something like

```
return obj1 == obj2 || obj1 != NULL && obj2 != NULL && *(void**)obj1 == *(void**)obj2;
```

but atomically in respect to object relocation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, we cannot get the Java object address by JNI, right?  I mean, the object in native code is not pointed to the corresponding Java object, right?

Comment: @tiger Right. In general, we cannot get object address via JNI.

Comment: thanks. I'm curious that is there any way to get it?

Comment: @tiger The short answer is no. But there might be a solution depending on what you want to do with this address.

Comment: `jobject` values do not change during execution of a JNI function, and your version of what `IsSameObject()` looks like internally does not explain the observed behaviour in any way. 'Atomically in respect [of] object relocation` does not mean anything within the execution of a JNI method.

Comment: @EJP Are you telling a JVM developer how JVM works? :)

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the comments. So, the root cause of the difference between "IsSameObject" and "obj1 == obj2" is not the relocation?  What is the real reason?